# When to use a field or a method in Rust structs?

Tags: struct, rust

being quite new to Rust and programming in general I have a basic question that is probably easily answered. Let's say I have a rectangle object, which has a width and a height, like so:

```
struct Rectangle1 {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}
```

I can create such an object with a new method:

```
fn new(width: u32, height: u32) -> Self {
    Rectangle1 { 
        width, 
        height,
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I want to use that object later and need its area, what is better practice? Have the area a field or a method?

So either I just implement this:

```
fn area(&self) -> u32 {
    self.width * self.height
}
```

Or, since area is inherent to that object, I give the object an "area" field:

```
struct Rectangle2 {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    area: u32,
}
```

And implement the new method like this instead:

```
fn new(width: u32, height: u32) -> Self {
    Rectangle2 { 
        width, 
        height,
        area: width * height,
    }
}
```

Now somewhere else in the code, when the area is needed:

```
let rect1 = Rectangle1::new(30, 50);

let rect2 = Rectangle2::new(30, 50);

println!(
    "The area of the rectangle 1 is {} square pixels.",
    rect1.area()
);
println!(
    "The area of the rectangle 2 is {} square pixels.",
    rect2.area
);
```

In this simple example I can't see when one would be better than the other. What should be preferred anyway? Is there one way that is less common because of something I am not aware of?

Comment: Maybe should you read about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). If you compute the `area` **field** then change `width` or `height`, then the value in `area` will not be correct. With the method the returned value will always match the dimensions..

Comment: @prog-fh So in a case where `width` and `height` do not change, using the `area` field doesn't cause any other problem and is a valid way to do things? Thanks for the useful link!

Comment: Nowadays, accessing memory is much more expensive (in time) than computing basic arithmetic. Adding a field to a struct will make it grow in size; if you have many of them to process, it could make a difference. Personally, I would not add such a field, except if a measure shows that all the time is spent in the multiplication, but it's very unikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR; it depends on the use case.

## IMHO

This starts to become opinionated very fast.  Generally speaking your answer will be driven by use-cases.

On modern systems, experience says that it's better to keep dependent params as functions and only optimize the caching of results as a special case.

## Example 1:

Length and height remain constant over life of the Rectangle; pre-calculating may be useful.   (Consider having to do it for 10^6 rectangles e.g.)

## Example 2:

Your height and length get modified ... then do you precalculate? Do you cache the result?

## Example 3:

You are constantly updating the third param based on the user updating any of the other two :-)

@prog-fh made a comment about accessing memory is expensive. I would say that you have to consider that both ways. Fetching two values into the CPU and calculating it can be potentially more expensive than accessing exactly one pre-calculated value.

so IMHO, and in line with what every one says,

It depends :-)

Comment: this is an interesting discussion of all cases. However if the OP is a novice, then IMO it's useful to point out that Example 1 will tend to be rare. Examples 2, 3 are much more common in daily practice. Making the data structure impossible to be inconsistent will be best for a novice. Use a method!